# how can i use the driver init in the setupModule

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

when i use unittest in python3, i tried like this:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

def setupModule():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('www.google.com')

def teardownModule():
    driver.close()

class test_01(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        driver.xxxx

    def tearDown(self):
        driver.xxxx

    def test_0001(self):
        driver.yyyy

    def test_0002(self):
        driver.zzzz

class test_02(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        driver.xxxx

    def tearDown(self):
        driver.xxxx

    def test_0001(self):
        driver.yyyy

    def test_0002(self):
        driver.zzzz
```

the driver in class and teardownModule can't be recognized. Is there any way to make it available?

I don't want to put `driver = webdriver.Firefox` out of def, as if i have 2 py file for different cases, it will init 2 or more firefox open firstly, nor cases in that file will be run or not, it will cause that browser always opened.

Comment: regarding the webdriver instantiation, does it have to be in module scope? usually, people will do it in class or function scope

Comment: if a page have many functions in it. i'd like create many class for different functions, so i need a common init out of the class, module setup and teardown is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend having a base class to handle the webdriver setup and teardown, i.e:

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

class test_01(BaseTest):
    def test_0001(self):
        self.driver.xxx

class test_02(BaseTest):
    def test_0002(self):
        self.driver.xxx
```

Comment: got it. it works for me. i used `setupclass` method instead. Thanks.